# QGIS: FieldCalculator stripping away a street address a certain way

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have set up some expression to strip away the address in multiple columns. While so far it works fine I have bit of a problem when it comes to letters.

I have a column in this table called "Address" as one example

```
Pieter de Smetstraat 1 A,2140 Antwerpen
```

This is the expression I use to "strip" the streetname and housenumber part:

```
replace("Address",(substr( "Address",strpos("Address",','))),'')
```

So it gets converted to this:

```
Pieter de Smetstraat 1 A
```

But I want to get it converted to this one:

```
Pieter de Smetstraat 1A
```

Keep in mind that the street address can be with spaces etc, special marks etc. So I need something that is universal to use, the street address can be one space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex expression to detect the space and remove it. Beware that parsing addresses is a can of worm... anything you do will create more issues (ex: ABC 2nd avenue)

```
regexp_replace(address,'(\\d+)[\\s-]+(\\w)','\\1\\2')
```

`(\\d+)`: find 1 number. Save in 1st capture group
`[\\s-]+`: find exactly one space or a `-`
`(\\w)`: find any word character, save in 2nd capture group

`\\1\\2`: replace the found expression (1 number followed by space or - followed by a word character) with the content of the 2 capture group (i.e. remove the space or -)

Comment: ..yeah thank you for the answer. But we have decided to go with my way for now. We just have to manually check those adresses. In the reference program. I will try to use your code in the future but if it leaves more problems that the hassle then we just leave it for now.Thank you anyway.